# python 2.7 2D dictionay

Tags: python, dictionary

```
Dict = {}
target = [
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18512'],
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18513']]
for input in target:

    temperature, hum, out = input[0], input[1], input[2:]
    Dict.setdefault(temperature, {}).setdefault(hum, out)
print Dict
```

I think the result is 
`{'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18512']}}, {'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18513']}}`

but actual result is only `{'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18512']}}`

how do I fix it?

Comment: Try changing the second "55.0" for something else, I believe you are setting the same key on an object.

Otherwise, try using a list instead of an object, as you seem to want multiple results and not a single one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is a list of dictionary:

```
list_of_dicts = []
target = [
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18512'],
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18513']]
for input in target:
    temperature, hum, out = input[0], input[1], input[2:]
    list_of_dicts.append({temperature: {hum: out}})
print list_of_dicts
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [{'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18512']}}, {'55.0': {'Index': ['0','18513']}}]
> ```

If you want to have a dictionary that have two `'55.0'` keys with nested dictionaries `'hum: out'` though, that is impossible since a dictionary can have unqiue keys, so your second item will always overwrite the first one.

---

Also a few notes:

1.) `setdefault()` is great for defaulting a item value for a key if the key doesn't exist, but in your use case it's counter productive since your keys are not unique, and therefore the value will get overwritten each time.  In this particular case, just create a dictionary for each item and `append()` to your resulting `list` is good enough.

2.) Try to avoid using reserved keywords like `input` or `dict`.  Although you have capitalized `Dict` it's easy to introduce bugs like overwriting some of the built-in functionalities.  The suggested naming convention for Python is to use lowercase and underscores for variables/attributes and CapitalizedWords for classes.  [Read more about it on the documentation here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions).  This is just a suggestion, you *can* have your own style.  But by following a consistent set of convention your code will be more readable for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
target = [
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18512'],
    ['55.0', 'Index', '0', '18513']]
main_dict = []
for tar in target:
    key, index, list_ = tar[0], tar[1], tar[2:]
    local_dict = defaultdict(dict)
    local_dict[key].update({index:list_})
    main_dict.append(dict(local_dict))
print(main_dict)
>>>[{'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18512']}}, {'55.0': {'Index': ['0', '18513']}}]
```